# parallax page not working responsively

Tags: responsive-design, parallax

The landing page for site http://www.kisadesign.co.uk works for desktop but when viewed on mobile and tablet the ability to scroll has gone so all you can see is the navigation and top block. It's responding to the media queries but can't scroll down. Any ideas on how to fix this?

Answer (score 2):

I'm not sure what jquery you use for the parallax scrolling but I use Skrollr for my website that it works pretty well for mobile devices.

https://github.com/Prinzhorn/skrollr

Comment: I'm using the same skrollr.js file

Comment: Got it working with the ID required that i didn't notice "skrollr-body"

Comment: thanks for the skrollr link ... better mobile support than most other options I've seen.